# How can I display byte encoded PDF in HTML?

Tags: html, django, pdf, bytestream, egnyte

My goal is to download a file from a file-sharing application (Egnyte) and render it in my own HTML. I'm working in Django.

I'm getting a 200 response from the storage service:

response.headers:

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8',...etc}
```

response.content: first 100 char. Type <Class Bytes>.

```
b'%PDF-1.6\r%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n12090 0 obj\r<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 2063/Length 4726/N 197/Type/ObjStm>>stream\r\n'
```

However, when I pass the response.content to the template.html as the source for an embed, the page is blank.

What am I missing?

I've tried using different html containers. I don't get any errors but in all cases the element is just blank.

```
<iframe src="b'%PDF-1.6\r%\xe2\xe3\...etc'">
```

Comment: The file is definitely PDF, I uploaded a .txt file and, when I request that, it sends back header: 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few days later I worked this out using Python, rather than embeding with JS.

```
    file = download_file(user_profile.token)
    
    with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as pdf:
        pdf.write(file.content)
    
    with open('file.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
```

Now, when I hit this view, Django serves the file beautifully.